# Magento 2.3 - Can't alter/insert into tables via data/schema patch (declarative schema)

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I'm using this [guide](https://github.com/bdcrops/BDC_Declarative) and [guide2](https://markshust.com/2019/02/19/create-product-attribute-data-patch-magento-2.3-declarative-schema/) as reference to add a custom attribute to `catalog_product`, but the patch isn't working.

Here is the Patch file (JKM\CustomModule\Setup\Patch\Data\AddShopAttribute.php):

```
<?php
namespace JKM\CustomModule\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddShopAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /** @var EavSetupFactory */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'shop', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Shop',
            'input' => 'select',
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error when running command `bin/magento setup:upgrade`:

> Module 'CustomModule': Warning: call_user_func()
>   expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class
>   'CustomModule\Setup\Patch\Data\AddShopAttribute' not found in
>   magento-root-folder/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchRegistry.php
>   on line 139

Here is PatchRegistry.php

```
 private function getDependencies(string $patch)
        {
            $depInstances = [];
            $deps = call_user_func([$patch, 'getDependencies']); // LINE 139
            $this->cyclomaticStack[$patch] = true;

            foreach ($deps as $dep) {
                if (isset($this->cyclomaticStack[$dep])) {
                    throw new \LogicException("Cyclomatic dependency during patch installation");
                }

                $depInstance = $this->registerPatch($dep);
                /**
                 * If a patch already have applied dependency - than we definently know
                 * that all other dependencies in dependency chain are applied too, so we can skip this dep
                 */
                if (!$depInstance) {
                    continue;
                }

                $depInstances = array_replace($depInstances, $this->getDependencies($this->patches[$dep]));
                $depInstances[$depInstance] = $depInstance;
            }

            unset($this->cyclomaticStack[$patch]);
            return $depInstances;
        }
```

Ive managed to create a table (db_schema.xml works) but its empty. For some reason Data/Schema Patch isn't working for me. Is the module path right (app/code/namespace/module)? What could be causing this behavior? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The namespace of your class, and the namespace in the error message are different - perhaps you have configured your module/setup class with the wrong namespaces?

Comment: @RobbieAverill Yeah, Namespace folder isn't showing up in the error message, but it's referenced in the class. Namespace folder "JKM" is refereced as "JKM\CustomModule\Setup\Patch\Data", so it seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your attribute parameters aren't completed. Try to use this code instead.

```
<?php
namespace JKM\CustomModule\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddShopAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /** @var EavSetupFactory */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'shop', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Shop',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
        ]);

        $groupName = 'Autosettings';
        $entityTypeId = $catalogSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $catalogSetup->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, 'Default');
        $attribute = $catalogSetup->getAttribute($entityTypeId, 'shop');
        if ($attribute) {
            $catalogSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $groupName,
                $attribute['attribute_id'],
                60
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to load values from a custom table to this select attribute? For example, I have a custom table `_shop` with some fields like `name`, `url` and so on. I want to load values from `_shop.name` (id to match integer type) in the select options instead of loading from `eav_attribute_int` cms tables.

Comment: You can do it changing the `source` class, you can create a class similar to the \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Boolean contains your values.